# How to expose class functionality in GWT

Tags: javascript, gwt, code-generation

I have a class library written in Java and want to convert it to Javascript. All methods are pretty simple and mostly have to do with manipulating collections. I have this one class, GameControl, which I could instantiate and I want its methods exposed to other Javascript code on the page.

I thought to use GWT. I have a running project in GWT which compiles, but I can't figure out how to expose my instance (+functionality) of the GameControl class.

I thought using JSNI to expose my object should work, but it didn't. This is the short version of how it look like right now:

**GameEntryPoint.java**

```
import com.google.gwt.core.client.EntryPoint;

public class GameEntryPoint implements EntryPoint {

    private GameControl _gameControl;

    @Override
    public void onModuleLoad() {
        _gameControl = new GameControl();
        expose();
    }


    public native void expose()/*-{
        $wnd.game = this.@game.client.GameEntryPoint::_gameControl;
    }-*/;

}
```

**GameControl.java**

```
package game.client;
public class GameControl {
    public boolean isEmpty(int id){
        // does stuff...
        return true;
    }   
}
```

So, GWT indeed compiles the code, and I see that there is a `GameControl_0` object being built and set into `$wnd.game`, but no `isEmpty()` method to be found.

My expected end result is to have a `window.game` as an instance of `GameControl` with all public methods `GameControl` exposes.

How can I do this?

**Edit**
As per `@jusio`'s reply, using JSNI to expose `window` properties explicitly worked, but it was too verbose. I'm trying the gwt-exporter solution. Now I have

**GameEntryPoint.java**

```
package game.client;

import org.timepedia.exporter.client.ExporterUtil;
import com.google.gwt.core.client.EntryPoint;

public class GameEntryPoint implements EntryPoint {

    @Override
    public void onModuleLoad() {
        ExporterUtil.exportAll();
    }

}
```

**RoadServer.java**

```
package game.client;

import org.timepedia.exporter.client.Export;
import org.timepedia.exporter.client.ExportPackage;
import org.timepedia.exporter.client.Exportable;


@ExportPackage("game")
@Export("RoadServer")
public class RoadServer implements Exportable {
    int _index;
    int _id;
    public RoadServer(int index,int id){
        this._id=id;
        this._index=index;
    }
}
```

but still none of the code is exported (specifically not `RoadServer`).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have exposed only instance of the `GameControl`. If you want to expose other methods, you'll have to expose them as well.
For example:

```
 public native void expose()/*-{
        var control = this.@game.client.GameEntryPoint::_gameControl;   
        var gameInstance = {
            gameControl: control,
            isEmpty:function(param){
              control.@game.client.GameEntryPoint::isEmpty(*)(param);   
            }  

        }


        $wnd.game = gameInstance;
    }-*/;
```

Also there is a framework called [gwt-exporter](http://code.google.com/p/gwt-exporter/), it might make things easier for you

Comment: Sorry for the delay in accepting. The first solution worked, but it's indeed very verbose. I can't seem to get `gwt-exporter` to work. I've added it to the project as an external JAR, modified the `GameEntryPoint` XML module file to inherit from `org.timepedia.exporter.Exporter` and set the `export` value to `yes`, and finally added the `Exportable` interface to every class in my project, but still a GWT compile doesn't product any of the code. I also tried adding `@Export` annotations to some. Have any idea what I might do?

Comment: @Yuval You also have to invoke `ExporterUtil.exportAll();` somewhere in you entrypoint, so the framework will actually expose your classes

Comment: Nothing has changed after I added this; perhaps the gwt-exporter is run into an error while processing my code? Is there any way I can see gwt-exporter working while it's working?

Comment: If it didn't threw any errors, it should be working. How do you try to access exported class?

Comment: I look for it in the JS code, both in `game.GameEntryPoint.nocache.js` and in either of the permutations (e.g. FE9DCF0DDC60172C41317F311A73B456.cache.html). None of the classes are there.

Comment: nooo, this is not how gwt-exporter works=) GWT exporter simply makes those objects available during runtime. E.g. if you include game.GameEntryPoint.nocache.js on html page, on the same page you can use can create objects of this type via Javascript. E.g. if you export some class with package "my" and name "GameClass", then in js you can simply call `var classObjetInstance= new my.GameClass() ` to create an object

Comment: But for that, I expect to find somewhere in the generated `game.GameEntryPoint.nocache.js` the reference to `GameClass`, which I don't. When I browse to `GameEntryPoint.html`, the `game` symbol has nothing inside it, just an empty object.

Comment: nope, it doesn't work this way. It will simply generate some code similar to the one I've written in my answer. I suggest you create another question related to GWT Exporter, and add as much information as you can about what you've tried, and what works for you.

Comment: Yeah, I think you are misunderstanding me. The code is nowhere to be found. I started a [new question here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10057844/gwt-exporter-doesnt-generate-code-java-to-javascript).

Answer (score 1):

This may help.

http://code.google.com/p/gwtchismes/wiki/Tutorial_ExportingGwtLibrariesToJavascript_en