# gwt-exporter doesn't generate code (Java to Javascript)

Tags: java, javascript, gwt, code-generation

I want to generate Javascript code from an existing Java project  ([original question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10029656/how-to-expose-class-functionality-in-gwt/10029797)).

I use GWT in conjunction with gwt-exporter. After I GWT compile, none of my types appear in any of the generated code.

I have

**GameEntryPoint.java**

```
package game.client;

import org.timepedia.exporter.client.ExporterUtil;
import com.google.gwt.core.client.EntryPoint;
import com.google.gwt.core.client.JavaScriptObject;

public class GameEntryPoint implements EntryPoint {

    @Override
    public void onModuleLoad() {
        ExporterUtil.exportAll();
    }

}
```

**RoadServer.java**

```
package game.client;

import org.timepedia.exporter.client.Exportable;

public class RoadServer implements Exportable {
    int _index;
    int _id;
    public RoadServer(int index,int id){
        this._id=id;
        this._index=index;
    }
}
```

There is no reference to `RoadServer` anywhere in my `war/` directory (`grep -Ri RoadServer war/*` matches only the `.class` files). Also, just to be sure, I opened the `war/GameEntryPoint.html` file in my browser (Firefox) and Firebug only sees `game_GameEntryPoint` as something that starts with `game`.

Any idea why this is not working?

P.S. I also tried specifying `@Export` and `@Export("RoadServer")` with `@ExportPackage("game")`. Nothing works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Aha, so looks like it is some bug in `ExporterUtil.exportAll()`. If class have non-empty constructor or doesn't have any methods it is not exported. But if you add an empty constructor to the exported class, and annotate non-empty constructor with `@Export` annotation it starts working

Also you can manually export a class:

```
public class GameEntryPoint implements EntryPoint {

    @Override
    public void onModuleLoad() {
        ExporterUtil.exportAll();
        GWT.create(RoadServer.class); //forcing to export road server
    }

}
```

But be aware that this way can sometimes export a class with errors

Comment: Thanks. I had to add the `@Export` annotation on both the constructor and the class for this to work, but it finally did. Also I had a problem with classes that had methods returning an array of a custom type. Changing those to populate a given array fixed that issue as well. It's a pity the docs on gwt-exporter don't list these issues.

Comment: Exportable classes need either a no-args constructor, or one that accepts a JavaScriptObject. It would be nice if it gave a compile time error or warning if it cannot export a class you have marked @Export for this reason.