# Turn off obfuscation for a particular class?

Tags: gwt

Is there a way to turn obfuscation off for a single class?

I need to do this because I have a native ios app that is running my app in a UIWebView - and I need to be able to call through to one of my GWT class methods - but since the classes are getting obfuscated, I can't do this.

Any ideas?

Another option I can think of is to write a pure javascript class myself that writes data to html5 storage. My native app would then call that manually created javascript method. Then my app can pick up the data from Storage and be on its way.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably looking for something similar to [gwt-export](http://code.google.com/p/gwt-exporter/) feature and not obsfuscation turn off feature.

Check out whether your question is similar to [How to expose class functionality in GWT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10029656/how-to-expose-class-functionality-in-gwt)